# How do you debug python program when it's run by a shell script?

Tags: python, bash

I'm running `run_keras.sh` from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/recommendation

If I put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in a python code, and hit up `. ./run_keras.sh`, it seems execution is stopped at the breakpoint but won't give me pdb command line.
(It just hangs)

How can I go about debugging?

run_keras.sh looks like (the relavant part )

```
 {

 for i in `seq 0 4`;
 do
   python -u "${SCRIPT_DIR}/${MAIN_SCRIPT}"
 done

 } |& tee "${LOCAL_TEST_DIR}/summary.log"
```

Comment: Interesting... I produced a simpler version (used dummy.py which just consisted of print("Hello World");import pdb;pdb.set_trace()) and ran this under Windows and had no issue getting to pdb command line (in fact, was surprised I didn't need to use winpty to get it to work from git bash)

Comment: Remove the  PIPE and `tee` part ?

Comment: Just for sanity checking, python2 or python3 (note that I just tried it with both and both worked in my simplified example which does use the -u (unbuffered mode, which was going to be my next guess for an issue)